# Box2d AS3 Flash simulating wind on top down view with friction

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d, game-physics, topdown

I am trying to make a top down game where you throw a disc using Box2d. The world has no gravity so the disc can be thrown and just bounces around the stage with the inertia and linear damping that I have set it with. Now, if I try to introduce wind using ApplyForce on an enter frame it will constantly push the disc in that direction until it hits a wall. What I am looking to do - with no luck so far - is give the stage (ground) some fiction so as the ball loses momentum it will eventually rest/stick. The code for the ApplyForce is as follows:

```
var xA = (Math.sin(windDir*(Math.PI/180)) * windSpeed * -1);
var yA = (Math.cos(windDir*(Math.PI/180)) * windSpeed );
var wind:V2 = new V2(xA, yA);
ball1.b2body.ApplyForce(wind, new V2(ball1.x, ball1.y));
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a friction joint to do this, but possibly not in the Flash port...?

Answer (score 0):

if it will have friction, it either wont move, or will move again until hits the wall, but slower.. its simple physics. you can slow down every object, but not with applyforce, because box2d is a simulator, and you want to do unrealistic thing.

Comment: I was thinking it would be kind of like a golf game where when the disc hits the ground the wind is competing with friction. Kind of like playing golf in a small room with wind, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply by the way!

Comment: in that case, you apply gravity (or force), then when it hits the ground, you remove it.

Comment: Thanks, csomakk. Do you know if there would be a way to make the force (windSpeed) relative or affected by the force applied to the disc from the throw?